changed config from devnet to mainnet, how to I migrate my tokens so I see hem when checking spl-token accounts?(2 question btw)
(Question 1)
before I did this; (so i could change metadata) I'd see my 80 mil tokens in the account made for the new minted token, now when I use spl-token accounts I just get
spl-token accounts
Token                                         Balance
-----------------------------------------------------

Obviously, I need to migrate or something but how? I have so many text files opened up and I dont event remember what seed phrases go with which accounts sometimes. Is there an easy way to do this?
(Question 2) so I can use the  metaboss create metadata -a 4srvHb8X4fzPabq6M5ezfD79dMqHxMVNKHPfCg997hcG -m metadata.json command, so I just put a file called metadata.json in my C:\Users\Keola.config\solana\ folder or is it more complicated than that?
